# Config File in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a reactjs application and have hosted in azure cloud. Now we want to implement the CI/CD process through Azure pipelines. I am quiet new in both the platforms. Need to know the process.

Currently, I have one file index.js where I have used the axios and have set the base URL to connect to the server. All my web services in different components class access this axios settings for accessing data from server. We have four environments, DEV,SIT, UAT and PROD. So for now I use to manually change the axios base URL and create the build and zip it and host it to the respective environments.

I need to understand for CI/CD what steps should I take. Most of the google finding suggested to have a config file. But how I can change my current implementation is a big challenge for me. For example my axios base URL, how it will take the value from the config file, or where I should create the config file, because when I create the build, all the js files are minified into one file and are put in the static folder. Apart from the static folder, the app icons and the files in the public folder of the project directory are listed (in the build folder). So shall I include a config file in the public folder or something else.

There are also webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js in the config folder of the project directory. Will it help. Because the requirement is first through Azure pipelines, the code will go to the DEV environment, then from DEV to SIT and from SIT to UAT and then to PROD. So subequently my axios Base URL should also change accordingly.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but you could create a json file and put your config data in there, i.e. server_config.json. It would not be minified as it is not a js file. Then you will need to read the json in your code to get all the settings. Your CI/CD can also read this fille should it need to.

You should also make sure that the json config file is ignored from version control so that each environment has to have its own file.

Comment: The problem with your approach is I have json file in the src.. but when I build the app, it is not shown in the build folder. The only place I can put it is in the public folder. But when I try to read the json file from the public folder in my src folder's component file, it is not allowing:


Module not found: You attempted to import ../public/serverconfig.json which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported. You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

Comment: Any help on this guys

Comment: Either symlink or having the build process copy the file to public, for example if you are using webpack there is a [plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) for that.